# JQuery to drag item and remove from animated list panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a list of draggable PNG icons, which can be dropped onto an area above the `div` that contains them. The containing `div` uses `.animate` to slide down, to minimize, when a tab button is clicked.

When I drag an image out of the bottom container, drop it on the page above and then click to minimize the bottom container, the dropped image also animates downwards. It stays attached to the original list.

How can I separate dragged items from the main list, once dropped, while still allowing them to be re-positioned with drag (and possibly dropped back into the bottom container if not wanted)?

My list structure in the container/tray:

```
    <div class="BottomToolsTray">
    <div class="IconsTrayTab">
    <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/contract_btn.png" class="OpenIconsBtn" data-toggleon="images/contract_btn.png" data-toggleoff="images/expand_btn.png" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="IconsTrayLabel">
    Icons Tray
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TextLabelsTab">
    Text Labels
    </div>
    <div class="ArrowsTab">
    Arrows
    </div>
    <div class="IconsPanelBox">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="IconGraphics">
     <ul class="clear">
    <li class="item" data-id="1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/Complex.png" alt="Complex">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-id="2">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/Simple.png" alt="Simple">
                </a>
            </li>

            <li data-id="3">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/2_3rd_IT_spend.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript part

```
<script>

    //Instructions Min/Max buttons

    $(document).ready(function(){

    //Icons Tray Min/Max buttons   

        $(".OpenIconsBtn").on('click',function(){
      if($(this).attr('src')==$(this).data('toggleon')){
       $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('toggleoff'))
       $(".BottomToolsTray").animate({"top":"57.3%"},500, function() {
          //$(".IconGraphics").show();
          $(".IconGraphics").fadeIn(100);
        });


       //SLIDE UP TOP BAR WHEN TOOL EXPANDED
       $(".instructions").slideUp(300);
       $(".ToptoggleBtn").attr('src',$(".ToptoggleBtn").data('toggleoff'))


      }else{
       $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('toggleon'))
          $(".IconGraphics").fadeOut(80);
       $(".BottomToolsTray").animate({"top":"579px"},500);
      }
    });
});


    //!-------------------------JQuery DRAG FUNCTION---------------------------------------//

    $(function () {

        // jQuery UI Draggable
        $(".IconGraphics li").draggable({
                      revert:false,
            drag:function () {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).closest(".IconGraphics").addClass("active");
            },

            // removing the CSS classes once dragging is over.
            stop:function (event, ui) {
                               $(this).removeClass("active").closest(".IconGraphics").removeClass("active");
            }
        });
                    $(".PageArea").droppable({
            tolerance:"touch",
            drop:function (event,ui) {
                var draggable = ui.draggable;
                var id = draggable.attr("data-id");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HW4tW/).

Here is an update...
Have this working in IE 9 now, other than the dropped objects snapping to top left when I want them just to drop where they are dropped. The lerger issue is that once switched to using helper and clone, the reposition of objects that are dropped has stopped working on iPad.
Can anyone offer help to fix this?
I'm not sure if it's a touch-punch js conflict, or an issue in my code that iPad doesn't like.

```
    Here's what I have:

    Top of script for js


    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/master.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="AppContainer">
    <div class="WhiteboardList">

    </div>


    <div class="IconGraphics">
    <ul class="clear">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Complex.png" alt="Complex">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Simple.png" alt="Simple">
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/2_3rd_IT_spend.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>


    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
var clone;
var a = 1;
    $(".IconGraphics li").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'hand'
    });

    $(".WhiteboardList").droppable({
                accept: ".IconGraphics li",
               // hoverClass: 'dropareahover',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                drop: function(event, ui)
                {

          var dropElemId = ui.draggable.attr("id");

          var dropElem = ui.draggable.html();

                  clone = $(dropElem).clone(); // clone it and hold onto the jquery object
          clone[0].id = "newId"+[a++];
          var newObject = clone[0].id;
          newObject.id = "newObject";
          $('#newId').css('position', 'absolute');
          $('#newId').css('float', 'left');

          //

          clone.draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    cursor: 'crosshair',
    stack: 'div',
    zIndex: '2500',

    });

                  $(this).append(clone);

           }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: have you tried cloning the element after it is dropped, and replacing the current element with the cloned one?

Comment: Hello Adjit, tahnk you for your reply. I did play around with the helper and clone but wasn't able to get it to work, and also have the cloned item then be repositionable, once dropped, or dragged back into the tray/container, if not needed.

I have been able to attached the dragged item to another div on the screen, when dropped, and be removed from the original div container, but again, it can't be repositioned or droppe back in the original container. Kind of stuck here.

Comment: Well, I suspect the reason you cannot select the cloned element is because of selector issues. Try selecting it like this `$( document ).on( "ready", "<your id or class>", function() {
  //Do stuff
});`

Comment: Thanks Adjit. As you can tell, I'm pretty new to jQuery. I tried this with my method of appending the dragged object to a parent, but still can't get the dropped object to reposition on drag. Will your proposed code above only work with a cloned object solution? Have you come across any good examples of what I'm trying to do? SO far, I haven't found anything like this, so I'm beginning to wonder if it is possible.

Comment: Hey Adjit...I was able to get the clone method working in IE but now it stopped working on iPad whne repositioning a dropped object.

Comment: See above update on my code.

Comment: Could have something to do with the way you set your css position. you are not selecting the proper object ID. When you set the ID you set it to `newId1` or whatever the index of `a` is. So there is no ID `#newId` You should be able to set the CSS like this : `clone.css({'position' : 'absolute', 'float': 'left'});` Although not sure why you need position to be absolute and float left, absolute positioning cannot be floated left